# How can i get entire role assignments from SP 2010 using the COM interface including the users in the AD groups and not the groups names?

Tags: development, permissions, client-object-model, roles

I've been trying to get all the RoleAssignments using the COM interface. the problem is that i get the AD user group names instead of the actual users inside the groups.

my code looks something like this:

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(#SiteURL);

RoleAssignmentCollection Roles = cc.Web.RoleAssignments;

IEnumerable<RoleAssignment> newRoleAssignmentsCollection = cc.LoadQuery(Role.Include(role => role.Member));

AsyncDelegate execDel = new AsyncDelegate(cc.ExecuteQuery);

execDel.BeginInvoke(arg => { cc.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (RoleAssignment RoleAssign in newRoleAssignmentsCollection)
{ 
    RoleAssign.Member.LoginName; // <------- Here is my problem!!! 
}

}, null);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the users which are inside the Active Directory group?

Thanks in advance, Itay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you have AD groups assigned permissions in that site and you want to know the names of the users that are members of the AD group?

If so, SharePoint doesn't know that information, you need to query it from AD directly.